# How to import a javascript module that exports a class in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to use the [recursive-iterator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recursive-iterator) npm package in TypeScript.

So I've created a .d.ts file with the Following content:

```
// declaring module will allow typescript to import the module
declare module 'recursive-iterator';
```

The javascipt module is basically this:

```
class RecursiveIterator {
...
}
module.exports = RecursiveIterator
```

At runtime, the Following code fails:

```
import { RecursiveIterator } from 'recursive-iterator';
…
for (let { node } of new RecursiveIterator(v, undefined, true)) {
          node.tracking = true;
        }
```

The error is:

> "recursive_iterator__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.RecursiveIterator is not a constructor"

I'm probably importing the module incorrectly but Don't know how to do.

Comment: When in doubt, try `import * as RecursiveIterator from 'recursive-iterator';` or `import RecursiveIterator from 'recursive-iterator';`.

Comment: Yep that's it. Thanks.